# Why does my string not match when reading user input from stdin?

Tags: string, rust, conditional-statements, user-input

I'm trying to get user input and check if the user put in "y" or "n". Surprisingly, in the below code, neither the `if` nor the `if else` case executes! Apparently, `correct_name` is neither "y" nor "n". How can that be? Am I doing my string conversion wrong or something?

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut correct_name = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut correct_name).expect("Failed to read line");
    if correct_name == "y" {
        println!("matched y!");
    } else if correct_name == "n" {
        println!("matched n!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`read_line` includes the terminating newline in the returned string. Add `.trim_right_matches("\r\n")` to your definition of `correct_name` to remove the terminating newline.

Comment: What about Windows, should it be "\r\n"?

Comment: It tells me bool` is not implemented for the type `&str when I add that

Comment: I realized it has to go in the if statement after I looked at docs. Thanks!

Comment: @ArtemGr That sounds right, but I don't know enough about Windows to be sure.

Comment: You should not need `as_slice`, since `String` implements `Deref<Target=str>`. `let line = io::stdin().read_line(); let trimmed = line.trim_right_chars(..);` should work.

Comment: And I'd suggest using just [`trim`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.StrExt.html#tymethod.trim) or [`trim_right`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.StrExt.html#tymethod.trim_right) instead of trying to worry about cross-platform newlines :-)

Comment: @Shepmaster `trim_right` would also eat other trailing whitespace, which might not be a good thing.

Comment: This was changed to [`trim_end`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_end)/[`trim_end_matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_end_matches) in 1.33

Answer (score 23):

`read_line` includes the terminating newline in the returned string.
To remove it, use [`trim_end`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_end) or even better, just [`trim`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim):

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut correct_name = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut correct_name)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let correct_name = correct_name.trim();

    if correct_name == "y" {
        println!("matched y!");
    } else if correct_name == "n" {
        println!("matched n!");
    }
}
```

This last case handles lots of types of whitespace:

> Returns a string slice with leading and trailing whitespace removed.
>
> ‘Whitespace’ is defined according to the terms of the Unicode Derived Core Property White_Space.

Windows / Linux / macOS shouldn't matter.

---

You could also use the trimmed result's length to truncate the original `String`, but in this case you should only use `trim_end`!

```rust
let trimmed_len = correct_name.trim_end().len();
correct_name.truncate(trimmed_len);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`chomp-nl` crate](https://crates.io/crates/chomp-nl) which provides a [`chomp` function](https://docs.rs/chomp-nl/0.1.1/chomp_nl/fn.chomp.html) which returns a string slice without the newline characters.

There is also a [trait `ChompInPlace`](https://docs.rs/chomp-nl/0.1.1/chomp_nl/trait.ChompInPlace.html) if you prefer to do this in-place.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.

Comment: What benefit / difference is there from `trim` / `trim_right` / `trim_right_matches`?

Comment: This is using the `trim_right_matches` function so the chomp function is a shortcut. There is also a trait for doing in-place trimming using `truncate` thought. So the benefit is mainly to have a shorter way to trim newlines.