# How rust language deals with console input?

Tags: rust

For this contrived rust code:

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Enter the number:");

    let constant = "!";
    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("failed to readline");

    print!("You entered {}{}\n", guess, constant);
    print!("You entered {}{}\n", &guess[..1], constant);

}
```

the output is

```
Enter the number:
1
You entered 1
!
You entered 1!
```

and not

```
Enter the number:
1
You entered 1!
You entered 1!
```

Is rust adding extra special such as newline chars to the input string?

Comment: After you entered the number 1, did you press Enter?

Comment: Yes, that should be the case. It seems includes rust includes a newline in the returned string, as shared by another user https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773313/why-does-my-string-not-match-when-reading-user-input-from-stdin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method that is ultimately called to read a line in this case is [`BufRead::read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line). That reads *up to and including* the newline delimiter, and places it in the buffer provided. So when you print `guess`, you are printing `1\n`, *then* the `!` character. The slice-then-print version does not include that trailing newline.

Comment: Of note: Ruby does the same, and presumably a lot of other languages do too. Ruby does a special method to trim the last character if it's a newline though.