# Why does my line from BufReader::lines not match?

Tags: string, file-io, rust, string-parsing

I am trying to parse a text file and find if a string is equal to current line I am on using `BufReader`:

```rust
let mut chapter = String::from("Chapter 1\n");

//open file
let file = File::open("document.txt")?;
let reader = BufReader::new(file);

for line in reader.lines() {
    if chapter.eq(&line.unwrap()) {
        println!("chapter found!");
    }
}
```

However, the if statement never returns true. How can I properly convert `line` from `reader.lines()` into a way I can find a match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [`ReadBuf::lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines):

> Each string returned will *not* have a newline byte (the `0xA` byte) or `CRLF` (`0xD`, `0xA` bytes) at the end.

Remove the `\n` from your search string:

```rust
let mut chapter = String::from("Chapter 1");
```

There's no reason to allocate the `String` here. A number of other changes:

```rust
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{self, BufRead, BufReader},
};

fn example() -> io::Result<()> {
    let chapter = "Chapter 1";

    let file = File::open("document.txt")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    for line in reader.lines() {
        if chapter == line.unwrap() {
            println!("chapter found!");
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

See also:

- [Why does my string not match when reading user input from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27773313/155423)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am really new to rust so I greatly appreciate it.