# Rust ParseIntError while asking input from users?

Tags: rust, user-input

I have a rust code in which it asks for the user input in a loop

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut string = String::new();

    loop {
        println!("Enter a value: ");
        let b = io::stdin().read_line(&mut string).expect("string");
        let val: u32 = string.trim().parse().expect("Error");

        println!("You typed: {:?}", val);
    }
}
```

This code works on the initial input but on inputting values the second time it panics and exists.

> thread 'main' panicked at 'Error: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', src/main.rs:13:20
> note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my string not match when reading user input from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773313/why-does-my-string-not-match-when-reading-user-input-from-stdin)

Answer (score 3):

According to [the rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line) `std::io::stdin::read_line` appends to the buffer so for the first iteration `string` contains for example `100`, then on the second iteration string will contain `100\n100` and \n cannot be parsed as an int.

You can fix this by clearing string every iteration or simply

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
  loop {
    let mut string = String::new();
    println!("Enter a value: ");
    let b = io::stdin().read_line(&mut string).expect("string");
    let val: u32 = string.trim().parse().expect("Error");

    println!("You typed: {:?}", val);
  }
}
```

Comment: FWIW the buffer will probably be `100\n` on the first iteration, as `read_line` does not trim the trailing newline. OP properly trims before parsing.

Answer (score 2):

You're not resetting the `string` in your loop, so if you enter 10 on first go and 5 on second go, your string is actually `"10\n5"` and of course the new-line character isn't a valid digit.

EDIT: To add "How do I solve this" --> Take smaller steps. If the parsing fails, print out what you're trying to parse.