# create_dir() adds weird question mark to the folder, when the folder name uses input

Tags: rust, directory

In one section of my program, it creates a folder that is named after the input that the user gives:

```
        println!("\nName your world\n");

        let mut name = String::new();

        io::stdin().read_line(&mut name).expect("Error Reading Input!");

        let mut name_path = format!("saves/{}",name);

        fs::create_dir(Path::new(&name_path)).unwrap();
        println!("\nWorld Created!\n");
```

It ran succesfully(I created a Folder called test_world), but when i viewed the folder, i noticed that it was named: test_world? I have run the program multiple times, and with different folder names, but it turns out the same(X?).
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUDb2.png)

Comment: `read_line` will include the newline character. Does this answer your question [Why does my string not match when reading user input from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27773313/2189130)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_line()` includes the trailing newline, if present. For example, try running this code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut s).unwrap();
    println!("Hello, world! '{}'", s);
}
```

to fix this, you can use `.trim()` to remove whitespace from the beginning and end of your input: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because of the newline character attached at the end of the string. You should call `.pop()` to remove the trailing newline or better yet the `.trim()` function that removes all preceding and trailing whitespace characters.

BTW you should use a `PathBuf` for working with paths
Here's the code

```rust
use std::{io, fs, path::PathBuf};

fn main() {
    println!("\nName Your World\n");
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    let trimmed_path = buffer.trim();

    let mut path = PathBuf::from("saves");
    path.push(trimmed_path);

    fs::create_dir(&path).unwrap();
}
```