# I've run a converter program using Rust, but the result is not what I want

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When I run the program , It has no error, but when I run it, it gives result that I don't want

The Program(Rust):

```
use std::io;


fn main() {
    println!("What temperature do you want to convert to?");
    println!("Celcius to Fahrenheit?,Please Type cf");
    println!("Fahrenheit to Celcius?,Please Type fc");
    let mut the_answer = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut the_answer).expect("The Answer");
    let x = String::from(the_answer);

    println!("You want to convert to : {}", x);
    println!("What temperature would you like to convert?");

    let mut temperature = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut temperature).expect("The Number");
    let temperature : i32 = match temperature.trim().parse(){
        Ok(temperature) => temperature,
        Err(_e) => {
            -1
        }
    };

    match x.as_str(){
        "cf\n" => println!("{}", cf(temperature)),
        "fc\n" => println!("{}", fc(temperature)),
        _ => println!("temperature = {:?}", x),
    }

}

fn cf(c: i32) -> i32 {
    (c * (9/5)) + 32
}

fn fc(f: i32) -> i32 {
    (f-32)*(5/9)
}
```

The Result:

```
   Compiling Converter v0.1.0 (C:\Users\NicMar\Documents\Rust Projects\Converter)
warning: crate `Converter` should have a snake case name
  |
  = note: `#[warn(non_snake_case)]` on by default
  = help: convert the identifier to snake case: `converter`

warning: `Converter` (bin "Converter") generated 1 warning
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.32s
     Running `target\debug\Converter.exe`
What temperature do you want to convert to?
Celcius to Fahrenheit?,Please Type cf
Fahrenheit to Celcius?,Please Type fc
cf
You want to convert to : cf

What temperature would you like to convert?
12
temperature = "cf\r\n"
```

the result is supposed to be temperature =53.6,

but it shows temperature = "cf\r\n"

Is there any mistake about my code? or I should change the version of the rust?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my string not match when reading user input from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773313/why-does-my-string-not-match-when-reading-user-input-from-stdin)

Answer (score 2):

Like you can see, the problem is that the Enter at the end is not trimmed and so `x` is `"cf\r\n"` which is neither `"cf"` nor `"fc"`, so we fall back to the default arm `println!("temperature = {:?}", x)`.

You just need to [`.trim()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) it (or even [`.trim_end()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_end)):

```rust
let x = String::from(the_answer.trim());
```

Comment: I'm sorry but when I changed it become 

```let x = String::from(the_answer.trim());```

The result will be:

```What temperature do you want to convert to?
Celcius to Fahrenheit?,Please Type cf
Fahrenheit to Celcius?,Please Type fc
fc
You want to convert to : fc
What temperature would you like to convert?
12
temperature = "fc"```

Comment: @NicholasMartin Use `"cf"` and `"fc"` in the `match` arms.