# Unexpected "10" when converting a string to ascii code in rust

Tags: rust, integer-overflow, brainfuck

I am trying to covert a string to an ascii code in rust to turn the string into BrainFuck code:

(The variable "input" is the string "hello" and this snippet starts at line 12)

```rust
for x in input.chars(){
    ascii = x as u8;
    println!("{}", ascii);
    if ascii > 86 {
      target = ascii - 86;
      output = output.clone() + "+[--------->++++++<]>";
      for x in 0..target{
        output = output + "+";
      output = output + ".>";
      }
    
    }else if ascii <= 86 {
      println!("{}", ascii);
      target = ascii - 86;
      output = output.clone() + "+[--------->++++++<]>";
      for x in 0..target{
        output = output + "-";
      output = output + ".>"
      }
    }
  }
  println!("{}", output)
```

However, the program fails with an 'attempt to subtract with overflow' at 25:16. This was unusual so I printed out all of the ascii values and got:

```
104
101
108
108
111
10
10
```

I am not sure why the two extra 10's are there, but they seem to be causing this subtract overflow. Why are these 10's being put into the ascii varable? Could it be that I am technically converting a string to base 10 and rust puts them there by default?

Comment: You have two branches, one for `ascii > 86` and one for `ascii <= 86`, but you have exactly the same code for either branch, including `target = ascii - 86`, which is certain to fail in the latter branch.

Comment: Copypasta strikes again!  Good catch @SvenMarnach

Comment: There are more problems with the code, e.g. `x as u8` will overflow if the input contains any Unicode codepoints ≥ 256.

Comment: The second `if` in the `else` branch is also unnecessary, and for iteratively building a string I recommend `output.push_str(...)` or `write!(&mut output, ...)`.

Comment: The 10s are newline characters.

Comment: Could you try `input.trim().chars()` instead of `input.chars()` I think like sven, is probably a newline char

Comment: Where does `input` come from? If you read it with `io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)`, then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27773313/5397009

Comment: @SvenMarnach, target = ascii - 86 is purposfully the same for both. (2nd comment), It is converting to to ascii which does not go over 255.

Comment: @Cody ASCII codes are always in the range 0–127. My point is that you can't subtract 86 from an unsigned number that is less than 86. It will overflow. Moreover, having an `if` with both branches doing exactly the same seems redundant.

Comment: @Cody if ascii is less than 86, you want target = 86 - ascii instead.

Comment: The 10s are linefeeds but they aren't the main problem; anything below 86, such as an 'H' or a space or a '!', would give target a negative value.

Comment: Linefeeds are important to be able to generate, anyway. I'd see it as a warning sign that the code you generate for them is like +[--------->++++++<]>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------.> rather than maybe ++++++++++.[-] or something.